# hashchange-can't refresh, can't link

Tags: jquery, hash

I have a problem with hashchange; I need the webpage to load the `#about` (one of my hashchanges) when the user clicks the `refresh` command. I also need certain pages to link to sections of my hashchange.

```
location.hash = '';

$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    var ImageContainer = $('.tabs>div'),
    hash = window.location.hash;

    if (hash === ''){
        hash = '#about';
    }

    ImageContainer.hide();
    ImageContainer.filter(hash).show(); 
    $('img').removeClass('selected');
    $('a[href="#123456"]', '.ImageContainer').addClass('selected');
}).trigger('hashchange');
```

Right now, because of the `location.hash = '';` I can not link to the hashchange sections I have setup, since it's being overruled by that command and loads `#about`.

I can delete that line of code and have my links work, but then the refresh fails to load `#about`. I have tried using a the meta tag to change the URL to no effect. I've tried to define an `if` statement. I've tried things like `window.location.reload();` which then continuously reloads the page. I've searched but haven't found a solution.

Comment: So what is the end result that you're trying to achieve with this code? Like are you making it so that when a link `href="#about"` is clicked, it will load a new page in?

Comment: I'm using `hashchange` and the `#about` is the name of one of the hashchange divs. When the user clicks `refresh` on the browser, the page is supposed to load the `#about`. I also want to be able to link to specific hash divs. Right now, I can have one or the other: `location.hash=''` gets the page to load the `#about`, but I can't link to the other hashchange divs. If I delete `location.hash=''`, I can link to the other hashchange divs, but the refresh button in the browser fails to load the `#about`.